# Place an image into a square div that handled with css pseudo element

Tags: html, css

Struggled with a basic css management issue.

I have created a div that need to be squared one, so I just added `:before` element to the div to achieve the square box.

Now the problem is:

I need to add image into the squared box, It can be a rectangle, square or lengthy image.

Please take a look at the snippet below:

the image with more height breaks the div squareness.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 60%;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box::before {
  padding-top: 100%;
  content: "";
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x1000" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I keep this div as a square one?

I have tried: image height 100%, 100vh & auto to make this, but not working well.

(please note: there is no problem if image is vertically or horizontally center)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/xgvc65r1/

Comment: `.left {width: 60%;}` is that 60% of the screen (60vwx60vw will do)? On a desktop, that square is hudge ...  do you need to shrink `img` / `.left`  to be set to a max-width too ? absolute does the job as is https://jsfiddle.net/jLzhbu4q/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus this seems as working.. can you add it as an answer for future reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from comment:

> `.left {width: 60%;}` is that 60% of the screen (60vw X 60vw will do)? On a desktop, that square is hudge ... do you need to shrink `img` / `.left` to be set to a `max-width` too ? absolute does the job as is https://jsfiddle.net/jLzhbu4q/

with the help of `object-fit` and `border-box`, you can add `padding`s and keep your image ratio.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 60%;
  background:green;
  padding:2em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}

.box img {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:5em;
  /*width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;*/
  width: auto; /* op's choice */
  max-width: 100%; /* op's choice */
  max-height: 100%;/* op's choice */
  margin: auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  object-fit:contain;
 
}

.box::before {
  padding-top: 100%;
  content: "";
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
  <div class="box">
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/800x1000" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used: `width: auto; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;` in image style property.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by changing the CSS with this code:

```
  .box {
        position: relative;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: red;
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
    }

    img {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .box::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: almost the same way :) great !

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
.div{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:100%;
}
.div:before{
  content:"";
  background-image:url("https://reactgo.com/static/171499b9f35ca9aaa3bdb4a99c2a7f41/6728c/crop-image-square.png");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  border-radius:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```